# Segfault occurs due to one line of code in C file and entire program does not run

Tags: c, file-io, serial-port, segmentation-fault, arm

I've created a C program to write to a serial port (/dev/ttyS0) on an embedded ARM system.  The kernel running on the embedded ARM system is Linux version 3.0.4, built with the same cross-compiler as the one listed below.

My cross-compiler is arm-linux-gcc (Buildroot 2011.08) 4.3.6, running on an Ubuntu x86_64 host (3.0.0-14-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP).  I have used the stty utility to set up the serial port from the command line.

Mysteriously, it seems that the program will refuse to run on the embedded ARM system if a single line of code is present.  If the line is removed, the program will run.

Here is a full code listing replicating the problem:

EDIT: I now close the file on error, as suggested in the comments below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>

int test();
void run_experiment();

int main()
{
    run_experiment();
return 0;
}

void run_experiment()
{
    printf("Starting program\n");
    test();
} 

int test()
{
    int fd;
    int ret;

    fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    printf("fd = %u\n", fd); 
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        close(fd);
        return 0;
    }

    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);

    printf("Now writing to serial port\n"); 

    //TODO:
    // segfault occurs due to line of code here
    // removing this line causes the program to run properly
    ret = write( fd, "test\r\n", sizeof("test\r\n") );

    if (ret < 0)
    {
        close(fd);
         return 0;
    }
close(fd);
return 1;
}
```

The output of this program on the ARM system is the following:

```
Segmentation fault
```

However, if I remove the line listed above and recompile the program, the problem goes away, and the output is the following:

```
Starting program
fd = 3
Now writing to serial port
```

What could be going wrong here, and how do I debug the problem?  Would this be an issue with the code, with the cross-compiler compiler, or with a version of the OS?

I have also tried various combinations of O_WRONLY and O_RDWR without O_NOCTTY when opening the file, but the problem still persists.

As suggested by @wildplasser in the comments below, I have replaced the test function with the following code, heavily based on the code at another site (http://www.warpspeed.com.au/cgi-bin/inf2html.cmd?..\html\book\Toolkt40\XPG4REF.INF+112).

However, the program still doesn't run, and I receive the mysterious `Segmentation Fault` again.

Here is the code:

```
int test()
{
   int fh;
   FILE *fp;
   char *cp;

   if (-1 == (fh = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR))) 
   {
      perror("Unable to open");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
   if (NULL == (fp = fdopen(fh, "w"))) 
   {
      perror("fdopen failed");
      close(fh);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   for (cp = "hello world\r\n"; *cp; cp++) 
   fputc( *cp, fp);

   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

This is very mysterious, since using other programs that I have written, I can use the `write()` function in a similar fashion to write to sysfs files, without any problem.

HOWEVER, if the program is exactly in the same structure, then I cannot write to /dev/null.

BUT I can successfully write to a sysfs file using exactly the same program!

If the segfault occurred at a particular line in the function, then I would assume that the function call would be causing the segfault.  However, the full program does not run!

UPDATE: To provide more information, here is the cross-compiler information used to build on ARM system:

$ arm-linux-gcc --v
Using built-in specs.
Target: arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi
Configured with: /media/RESEARCH/SAS2-version2/device-system/buildroot/buildroot-2011.08/output/toolchain/gcc-4.3.6/configure --prefix=/media/RESEARCH/SAS2-version2/device-system/buildroot/buildroot-2011.08/output/host/usr --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --target=arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-sysroot=/media/RESEARCH/SAS2-version2/device-system/buildroot/buildroot-2011.08/output/host/usr/arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi/sysroot --with-build-time-tools=/media/RESEARCH/SAS2-version2/device-system/buildroot/buildroot-2011.08/output/host/usr/arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi/bin --disable-__cxa_atexit --enable-target-optspace --disable-libgomp --with-gnu-ld --disable-libssp --disable-multilib --enable-tls --enable-shared --with-gmp=/media/RESEARCH/SAS2-version2/device-system/buildroot/buildroot-2011.08/output/host/usr --with-mpfr=/media/RESEARCH/SAS2-version2/device-system/buildroot/buildroot-2011.08/output/host/usr --disable-nls --enable-threads --disable-decimal-float --with-float=soft --with-abi=aapcs-linux --with-arch=armv5te --with-tune=arm926ej-s --disable-largefile --with-pkgversion='Buildroot 2011.08' --with-bugurl=http://bugs.buildroot.net/
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.3.6 (Buildroot 2011.08)

Here is the makefile that I am using to compile my code:

```
CC=arm-linux-gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall
datacollector: datacollector.o 

clean:
    rm -f datacollector datacollector.o
```

UPDATE: Using the debugging suggestions given in the comments and answers below, I found that the segfault was caused by including the `\r` escape sequence in the string.  For some strange reason, the compiler doesn't like the `\r` escape sequence, and will cause a segfault without running the code.

If the `\r` escape sequence is removed, then the code runs as expected.

Thus, the offending line of code should be the following:

ret = write( fd, "test\n", sizeof("test\n") );

So for the record, a full test program that actually runs is the following (could someone comment?):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>

int test();
void run_experiment();

int main()
{
    run_experiment();

return 0;
}

void run_experiment()
{
    printf("Starting program\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    test(); 
}


int test()
{
    int fd;
    int ret;
    char *msg = "test\n";
    // NOTE: This does not work and will cause a segfault!
    // even if the fflush is called after each printf,
    // the program will still refuse to run
    //char *msg = "test\r\n";

    fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    printf("fd = %u\n", fd); 
    fflush(stdout);

    if (fd < 0) 
    {
       close(fd);
       return 0;
    }

    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);

    printf("Now writing to serial port\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    ret = write( fd, msg, strlen(msg) );

    if (ret < 0)
    {
        close(fd);
        return 0;
    }

    close(fd);

return 1;
}
```

EDIT: As an aside to all of this, is it better to use:

```
ret = write( fd, msg, sizeof(msg) );
```

or is it better to use:

```
ret = write( fd, msg, strlen(msg) );
```

**Which is better? Is it better to use sizeof() or strlen()?  It appears that some of the data in the string is truncated and not written to the serial port using the sizeof() function.**

As I understand from Pavel's comment below, it is better to use `strlen()` if `msg` is declared as `char*`.

Moreover, it appears that gcc is not creating a proper binary when the escape sequence `\r` is being used to write to a tty.

Referring to the last test program given in my post above, the following line of code causes a segfault without the program running:

```
char *msg = "test\r\n";
```

As suggested by Igor in the comments, I have run the gdb debugger on the binary with the offending line of code.  I had to compile the program with the `-g` switch. 
**The gdb debugger is being run natively on the ARM system, and all binaries are being built for the ARM architecture on the host using the same Makefile.  All binaries are being built using the arm-linux-gcc cross-compiler.**

The output of gdb (running natively on the ARM system) is as follows:

```
GNU gdb 6.8
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi"...
"/programs/datacollector": not in executable format: File format not recognized
(gdb) run
Starting program:
No executable file specified.
Use the "file" or "exec-file" command.
(gdb) file datacollector
"/programs/datacollector": not in executable format: File format not recognized
(gdb)
```

However, if I change the single line of code to the following, the binary compiles and runs properly. Note that the `\r` escape sequence is missing:

```
char *msg = "test\n";
```

Here is the output of gdb after changing the single line of code:

```
GNU gdb 6.8
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi"...
(gdb) run
Starting program: /programs/datacollector
Starting program
fd = 4
Now writing to serial port
test
Program exited normally.
(gdb)
```

UPDATE:

As suggested by Zack in an answer below, I have now ran a test program on the embedded
Linux system.  Although Zack gives a detailed script to run on the embedded system, I was
unable to run the script due to the lack of development tools (compiler and headers) installed in the root file system.
In lieu of installing these tools, I simply compiled the nice test program that Zack provided in the script and
used the strace utility.  The strace utility was run on the embedded system.

At last, I think that I understand what is happening.

The bad binary was transferred to the embedded system over FTP, using an SPI-to-Ethernet bridge (KSZ8851SNL).
There is a driver for the KSZ8851SNL in the Linux kernel.

**It appears that either the Linux kernel driver, the proftpd server software running on the embedded system, or the actual hardware itself (KSZ8851SNL)
was somehow corrupting the binary.  The binary runs well on the embedded system.**

Here is the output of strace on the testz binary transferred to the embedded Linux system over the Ethernet serial link:

Bad binary tests:

```
# strace ./testz /dev/null
execve("./testz", ["./testz", "/dev/null"], [/* 17 vars */]) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|0x4000000, -1, 0) = 0x40089000
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
Segmentation fault

# strace ./testz /dev/ttyS0
execve("./testz", ["./testz", "/dev/ttyS0"], [/* 17 vars */]) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|0x4000000, -1, 0) = 0x400ca000
--- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
Segmentation fault
#
```

Here is the output of strace on the testz binary transferred on SD card to the embedded Linux system:

Good binary tests:

```
#  strace ./testz /dev/null
execve("./testz", ["./testz", "/dev/null"], [/* 17 vars */]) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|0x4000000, -1, 0) = 0x40058000
open("/lib/libc.so.0", O_RDONLY)        = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=298016, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|0x4000000, -1, 0) = 0x400b8000
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\240\230\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
mmap2(NULL, 348160, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x40147000
mmap2(0x40147000, 290576, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED, 3, 0) = 0x40147000
mmap2(0x40196000, 4832, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED, 3, 0x47) = 0x40196000
mmap2(0x40198000, 14160, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x40198000
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x400b8000, 4096)                = 0
stat("/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=25296, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|0x4000000, -1, 0) = 0x400c4000
set_tls(0x400c4470, 0x400c4470, 0x4007b088, 0x400c4b18, 0x40) = 0
mprotect(0x40196000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x4007a000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B115200 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B115200 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
open("/dev/null", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK) = 3
write(3, "1\n", 2)                      = 2
write(3, "12\n", 3)                     = 3
write(3, "123\n", 4)                    = 4
write(3, "1234\n", 5)                   = 5
write(3, "12345\n", 6)                  = 6
write(3, "1\r\n", 3)                    = 3
write(3, "12\r\n", 4)                   = 4
write(3, "123\r\n", 5)                  = 5
write(3, "1234\r\n", 6)                 = 6
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?


#  strace ./testz /dev/ttyS0
execve("./testz", ["./testz", "/dev/ttyS0"], [/* 17 vars */]) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|0x4000000, -1, 0) = 0x400ed000
open("/lib/libc.so.0", O_RDONLY)        = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=298016, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|0x4000000, -1, 0) = 0x40176000
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\240\230\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
mmap2(NULL, 348160, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x40238000
mmap2(0x40238000, 290576, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED, 3, 0) = 0x40238000
mmap2(0x40287000, 4832, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED, 3, 0x47) = 0x40287000
mmap2(0x40289000, 14160, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x40289000
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x40176000, 4096)                = 0
stat("/lib/ld-uClibc.so.0", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=25296, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|0x4000000, -1, 0) = 0x400d1000
set_tls(0x400d1470, 0x400d1470, 0x40084088, 0x400d1b18, 0x40) = 0
mprotect(0x40287000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x40083000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B115200 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B115200 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK) = 3
write(3, "1\n", 21
)                      = 2
write(3, "12\n", 312
)                     = 3
write(3, "123\n", 4123
)                    = 4
write(3, "1234\n", 51234
)                   = 5
write(3, "12345\n", 612345
)                  = 6
write(3, "1\r\n", 31
)                    = 3
write(3, "12\r\n", 412
)                   = 4
write(3, "123\r\n", 5123
)                  = 5
write(3, "1234\r\n", 61234
)                 = 6
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

Comment: What *does* work? Can you write 0 bytes to that fd? Can you write 1 byte of that string to that fd?

Comment: @nickgrim: Thank you very much for this comment.  Strangely enough, it seems to be that one line of code that causes the entire program to segfault.  It seems that program execution does not reach the line, and I cannot write 0 bytes nor 1 byte of the string to the fd.

Comment: Maybe write is not allowed for non-seekable fd's? Try a loop around fputc() : `for (cp = "hello world\r\n"; *cp; cp++) fputc( *cp, fp);`, oops: that needs an fdopen, of course ...

Comment: Does it work if you use `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0L);` instead of the `fcntl` call you have?

Comment: @interjay: Thanks for your suggestion, interjay.  Strangely enough, it does not work with `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0L);` and it does not work either if I remove the call to `fnctl()`. The issue seems to be the one line of code above.

Comment: Probably not related to the problem, but shouldn't you close `fd` before `if (ret < 0) return 0;`?

Comment: @wildplasser:  Thank you very much for your good suggestion. I have updated the test program to check.  I now think that the problem might be much deeper than just the program code.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, that is a good catch.  I tend to be very sloppy when writing example test code.

Comment: I don't really see how it could be an issue, but maybe try this:
`const char msg[] = "test\r\n";

ret = write( fd, msg, strlen(msg));
`

Comment: I was just delving into the kernel source. SEGV is a very weird errno for a write(). Have you tried making the string writable ? Have you tried some other iocntl()s, like setting the speed/handshake? @Igor: my idea, too. Should be impossible, though...

Comment: @Igor: Thanks Igor, that is an interesting suggestion.  Strangely enough, the program still segfaults.

Comment: @wildplasser:  I agree; it is very weird, but it seems that the program SEGV on startup.  Thus, none of the `printf()` are called.  The program  simply segfaults on startup.  I've tried making the string writable, but not other iocntl()s.

Comment: I would wonder if someone could run my simple test program on an ARM system.  Perhaps this would help to show where the problem is?  Ideally, the write could be to the currently active tty, which could be /dev/ttyS0.

Comment: I have seen a similar problem with function calls on different ARM system. There were several required command line parameters for the compiler (_-fomit-frame-pointer_ etc). When I removed some of those parameters the program would compile but it was showing all kinds of strange behavior including segfaults. The sytem was uClinux running on ARM-based machine, arm-elf-gcc cross-compiler. Try checking your system documentation for details on proper compiler configuration.

Comment: You have `fdopen(fh, "r")` in the second piece of code. Shouldn't that be `fdopen(fh, "w")`?

Comment: @MRAB: Yes, you are right.  The test program has been updated above.  It is a bit tricky to debug if the full program does not run.

Comment: If you can, you should run the program under `strace` -- that will reveal something about how much of the program gets executed before the segfault happens.

Comment: @Pavel: Thank you for your suggestion!  I am using the AT91SAM9G20 ARM processor, and the compiler has been built using Buildroot. I have written my own makefile, with not too many additional command-line parameters. I will elaborate in my original question above.

Comment: @Pavel: Maybe there is something wrong with the required command-line parameters?  I haven't touched anything from the Buildroot default build for AT91SAM9260 (which is similar to the AT91SAM9G20).

Comment: @Zack: Thanks Zack, that is an excellent suggestion.

Comment: I think you should just run it under the debugger - that will show you the exact place it's crashing.

Comment: @Igor: Thanks for your suggestion, Igor.  I used gdb to debug the program, and the program does not run.  The gdb debugger tells me that `"/programs/datacollector": not in executable format: File format not recognized`.  Perhaps this indicates that the compiler is not creating proper code.

Comment: That is more likely to indicate that you ran a `gdb` built for x86 on an ARM executable or vice versa.

Comment: @Zack: Thank you for suggesting this.  I have now checked that the gdb was built for ARM using Buildroot, and the gdb is being natively run on the ARM system.  I've also checked the Makefile, and both programs are being compiled on the host with the arm-linux-gcc compiler.  I have updated my question above to reflect this.

Comment: What is the output of "file /programs/datacollector" for the broken version of the executable?

Comment: A '\r' symbol makes executable image broken, wow o.O  I wonder, what are the gcc creators going to say about this. As for `sizeof` vs `strlen`, `sizeof` is a compile time operator, while `strlen` is a function which calculates null-terminated string length at runtime (excluding the terminating zero). Have in mind that if `msg` declared as `char*`, `sizeof(msg)` will return sizeof pointer type (most probably 4 for your system). For `const char arr[] = "abc";` sizeof(arr) will provide a number of bytes in arr, including the terminating `\0`

Comment: @Zack: The output of the file command on the broken executable: `datacollector: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped`

Comment: @Pavel: Thanks for pointing this out; I think that I understand now it is better to use `strlen()` if `msg` is declared as `char*`.

Comment: Okay, um, would you mind putting both the broken and the good executables somewhere I can download them?  I'm pretty sure I can figure out what's wrong by comparing them, and it'll be a lot faster than doing it here one question at a time.  Please make sure the *only* difference is the `\r` -- in the "good" executable, have `char *msg = "testX\n"` instead of `char *msg = "test\r\n"`.

Comment: Oh, if `"testX\n"` makes it crash too, that's valuable information - in that case I want to see `"test\n"` and `"testX\n"`.

Comment: @Zack: Sure, I've put the broken and the good executables in a tar.gz file and made them available for download here: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-xY4xORAoEDYWI4OGNlNjUtZmE2OC00ZDFiLThiNjQtODc4MTJjZGNjYjVh.  I've also included source and Makefiles.

Comment: @Zack: As far as I know, `"testX\n"` does not cause the crash.  It is only `char *msg = "testX\r\n"` that causes the crash.  Thank you for taking a look at this.  Are you suspecting problems with UNICODE?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT:** Read on for gory details, but the quick answer is, your FTP client is corrupting your program.  This is an intentional feature of FTP, which can be turned off by typing `binary` at the FTP prompt before `get whatever` or `put whatever`. If you're using a graphical FTP client it should have a checkbox somewhere with the same effect.  Or switch to `scp`, which does not have this inconvenient feature.

---

First off, there is no difference in the generated assembly code
between (one of the) working object files and the broken object file.

```
$ objdump -dr dc-good.o > dc-good.s
$ objdump -dr dc-bad.o > dc-bad.s
$ diff -u dc-good.s dc-bad.s
--- dc-good.s   2012-01-21 08:20:05.318518596 -0800
+++ dc-bad.s    2012-01-21 08:20:10.954566852 -0800
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@

-dc-good.o:     file format elf32-littlearm
+dc-bad.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


 Disassembly of section .text:
```

In fact, there are only two *bytes* that differ between the good and
bad object files.  (You misunderstood what I was asking for with
`"test\r\n"` versus `"testX\n"`: I wanted the two strings to be the
same *length*, so that everything would have the same offset in the
object files.  Fortunately, your compiler padded the shorter string to
the same length as the longer string, so everything has the same
offset anyway.)

```
$ hd dc-good.o > dc-good.x
$ hd dc-bad.o > dc-bad.x
$ diff -u1 dc-good.x dc-bad.x
--- dc-good.x   2012-01-21 08:17:28.713174977 -0800
+++ dc-bad.x    2012-01-21 08:17:39.129264489 -0800
@@ -154,3 +154,3 @@
 00000990  53 74 61 72 74 69 6e 67  20 70 72 6f 67 72 61 6d  |Starting program|
-000009a0  00 00 00 00 74 65 73 74  58 0a 00 00 2f 64 65 76  |....testX.../dev|
+000009a0  00 00 00 00 74 65 73 74  58 0d 0a 00 2f 64 65 76  |....testX.../dev|
 000009b0  2f 74 74 79 53 30 00 00  66 64 20 3d 20 25 75 0a  |/ttyS0..fd = %u.|
@@ -223,3 +223,3 @@
 00000de0  61 72 69 65 73 2f 64 61  74 61 63 6f 6c 6c 65 63  |aries/datacollec|
-00000df0  74 6f 72 2d 62 61 64 2d  62 69 6e 61 72 79 2d 32  |tor-bad-binary-2|
+00000df0  74 6f 72 2d 62 61 64 2d  62 69 6e 61 72 79 2d 31  |tor-bad-binary-1|
 00000e00  00 46 49 4c 45 00 5f 5f  73 74 61 74 65 00 5f 5f  |.FILE.__state.__|
```

The first difference is the difference that should be there: `74 65 73
74 58 0a 00 00` is the correct encoding of `"test\n"` (with one byte
of padding), `74 65 73 74 58 0d 0a 00` is the correct encoding of
`"test\r\n"`.  The other difference appears to be debugging
information: the name of the directory in which you compiled the
programs. This is harmless.

The object files are as they should be, so at this point we can rule
out a bug in the compiler or the assembler.  Now let's look at the
executables.

```
$ hd dc-good > dc-good.xe
$ hd dc-bad > dc-bad.xe
$ diff -u1 dc-good.xe dc-bad.xe
--- dc-good.xe  2012-01-21 08:31:33.456437417 -0800
+++ dc-bad.xe   2012-01-21 08:31:38.388480238 -0800
@@ -120,3 +120,3 @@
 00000770  f0 af 1b e9 53 74 61 72  74 69 6e 67 20 70 72 6f  |....Starting pro|
-00000780  67 72 61 6d 00 00 00 00  74 65 73 74 58 0a 00 00  |gram....testX...|
+00000780  67 72 61 6d 00 00 00 00  74 65 73 74 58 0d 0a 00  |gram....testX...|
 00000790  2f 64 65 76 2f 74 74 79  53 30 00 00 66 64 20 3d  |/dev/ttyS0..fd =|
@@ -373,3 +373,3 @@
 00001750  63 6f 6c 6c 65 63 74 6f  72 2d 62 61 64 2d 62 69  |collector-bad-bi|
-00001760  6e 61 72 79 2d 32 00 46  49 4c 45 00 5f 5f 73 74  |nary-2.FILE.__st|
+00001760  6e 61 72 79 2d 31 00 46  49 4c 45 00 5f 5f 73 74  |nary-1.FILE.__st|
 00001770  61 74 65 00 5f 5f 67 63  73 00 73 74 64 6f 75 74  |ate.__gcs.stdout|
```

Same two differences, different offsets within the executable.  This
is also as it should be.  We can rule out a bug in the linker as well
(if it was screwing up the address of the string, it would have to be
screwing it up the same way in both executables and they both ought to
crash).

At this point I think we are looking at a bug in your C library or
kernel.  To pin it down further, I would like you to try this test
script.  Run it as `sh testz.sh` on the ARM board, and send us the
complete output.

```
#! /bin/sh

set -e
cat >testz.c <<\EOF
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define W(f, s) write(f, s, sizeof s - 1)

int
main(int ac, char **av)
{
  int f;
  if (ac != 2) return 2;
  f = open(av[1], O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK);
  if (f == -1) return 1;

  W(f, "1\n");
  W(f, "12\n");
  W(f, "123\n");
  W(f, "1234\n");
  W(f, "12345\n");

  W(f, "1\r\n");
  W(f, "12\r\n");
  W(f, "123\r\n");
  W(f, "1234\r\n");

  close(f);
  return 0;
}
EOF

arm-linux-gcc -Wall -g testz.c -o testz
set +e
strace ./testz /dev/null
echo ----
strace ./testz /dev/ttyS0
echo ----
exit 0
```

---

I've looked at the damaged binary you provided and now I know what's wrong.

```
$ ls -l testz*
-rwxr-x--- 1 zack zack 7528 Dec 31  1979 testz-bad
-rwxr-x--- 1 zack zack 7532 Jan 21 16:35 testz-good
```

Ignore the odd datestamp; see how the `-bad` version is four bytes smaller than the `-good` version?  There were exactly four `\r` characters in the source code.  Let's have a look at the differences in the hex dumps.  I've pulled out the interesting bit of the diff and shuffled it around a little to make it easier to see what's going on.

```
 00000620  00 00 00 00 31 32 33 34  0a 00 00 00 31 32 33 34  |....1234....1234|

-00000630  35 0a 00 00 31 0d 0a 00  31 32 0d 0a 00 00 00 00  |5...1...12......|
+00000630  35 0a 00 00 31 0a 00 31  32 0a 00 00 00 00 31 32  |5...1..12.....12|

-00000640  31 32 33 0d 0a 00 00 00  31 32 33 34 0d 0a 00 00  |123.....1234....|
+00000640  33 0a 00 00 00 31 32 33  34 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00  |3....1234.......|

-00000650  00 00 00 00 68 84 00 00  1c 84 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....h...........|
+00000650  68 84 00 00 1c 84 00 00  00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  |h...............|
```

The file transfer is replacing `0d 0a` (that is, `\r\n`) sequences with `0a` (just `\n`). This causes everything after this point in the file to be displaced four bytes from where it's supposed to be.  The code is before this point, and so are all the ELF headers that the *kernel* looks at, which is why you don't get

```
execve("./testz-bad", ["./testz-bad", "/dev/null"], [/* 36 vars */]) = -1 ENOEXEC (Exec format error)
```

from the test script; instead, you get a segfault inside the dynamic loader, because the DYNAMIC segment (which tells the dynamic loader what to do) *is* after the displacement starts.

```
$ readelf -d testz-bad 2> /dev/null

Dynamic section at offset 0x660 contains 13 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x00000035 (<unknown>: 35)              0xc
 0x0000832c (<unknown>: 832c)            0xd
 0x00008604 (<unknown>: 8604)            0x19
 0x00010654 (<unknown>: 10654)           0x1b
 0x00000004 (HASH)                       0x1a
 0x00010658 (<unknown>: 10658)           0x1c
 0x00000004 (HASH)                       0x4
 0x00008108 (<unknown>: 8108)            0x5
 0x0000825c (<unknown>: 825c)            0x6
 0x0000815c (<unknown>: 815c)            0xa
 0x00000098 (<unknown>: 98)              0xb
 0x00000010 (SYMBOLIC)                   0x15
 0x00000000 (NULL)                       0x3
```

Contrast:

```
$ readelf -d testz-good

Dynamic section at offset 0x660 contains 18 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.0]
 0x0000000c (INIT)                       0x832c
 0x0000000d (FINI)                       0x8604
 0x00000019 (INIT_ARRAY)                 0x10654
 0x0000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)               4 (bytes)
 0x0000001a (FINI_ARRAY)                 0x10658
 0x0000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ)               4 (bytes)
 0x00000004 (HASH)                       0x8108
 0x00000005 (STRTAB)                     0x825c
 0x00000006 (SYMTAB)                     0x815c
 0x0000000a (STRSZ)                      152 (bytes)
 0x0000000b (SYMENT)                     16 (bytes)
 0x00000015 (DEBUG)                      0x0
 0x00000003 (PLTGOT)                     0x10718
 0x00000002 (PLTRELSZ)                   56 (bytes)
 0x00000014 (PLTREL)                     REL
 0x00000017 (JMPREL)                     0x82f4
 0x00000000 (NULL)                       0x0
```

The debugging information is also after the displacement, which is why gdb didn't like the program.

---

So why this very particular corruption?  It's not a bug in anything; it's an intentional feature of your FTP *client*, which defaults to transferring files in "text mode", which means (among other things) that it converts DOS-style line endings (`\r\n`) to Unix-style (`\n`).  Because that would be what you wanted if this were 1991 and you were transferring text files off your IBM PC to your institutional file server.  It is basically never what is wanted nowadays, even if you *are* moving text files around.  Fortunately, you can turn it off: just type `binary` at the FTP prompt before the file transfer commands.  *Un*fortunately, as far as I know there is no way to make that *stick*; you have to do that every time.  I recommend switching to `scp`, which always transfers files verbatim and is also easier to operate from build automation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed test script!  This is extremely enlightening.  Although I do not have development tools installed on the embedded system, I think that the test program given in the script helped to rule out problems with the standard library or with the Linux system.  I've updated my answer above, and I've also provided binaries demonstrating the corruption that happens when they are transferred over FTP (https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-xY4xORAoEDYmMxMmU4N2UtNDYzZi00NDI4LThjZjQtZDBiNmEyNGUwMzRh).

Comment: If you could take a look at these binaries and update your answer, I will accept your answer. Thank you once again for your detailed and good advice.

Comment: Excellent analysis. I did not even suspect that FTP was part of the OP's toolchain. It's like the spanish inquisition ...

Comment: @Zack: Amazing, extremely detailed answer.  That's incredible, and thank you so much for shedding light on this issue!  Over the past few years, I've designed the circuit boards for a number of embedded systems running Linux, and I have to say that the segmentation fault error was sometimes messing things up for me.  Needless to say, all of my binaries were transferred over an FTP link.

Comment: @wildplasser: I love StackOverflow!

Comment: @Zack: I was using FileZilla to transfer the binaries, but I think that scp might work much better.  Thank you for suggesting this.

Comment: This is definitely one of the most peculiar problems I've seen here.

Answer (score 1):

First things first - the fact that you only see the seg fault is NOT indicative that the program failed to run at all. What happens is that the output from the printf calls is line buffered, and when the program seg faults, it's never written out.

If you add 
fflush(stdout);
after every printf, you'll see your output prior to the segfault.

Now, in your original program, what's the point of the fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0); call? What are you trying to achieve with it? Are you trying to turn off non-blocking mode? What if you don't make that call?

As to your second test, I see that you are using perror, but again the lack of error messages doesn't tell you that the program isn't running - it just tells you that you didn't get any error messages, and you still aren't flushing stdout, so you'll never see the printf from run_experiment.

I also see that in your second test you're doing an fdopen with read mode, then trying to write to that FILE pointer. While that certainly shouldn't crash, it also certainly shouldn't work.

Now, outside of your program, are you sure the serial port works OK? Try doing 'cat  > /dev/ttyS0' and see what happens, just to be sure it's not something wonky with the hardware.

Comment: `perror` writes to `stderr`, which *ought* to be line-buffered.  If this were a normal hosted C environment, `stdout` would be line-buffered too via tty detection, but that might not be true for this embedded system.

Comment: @Zack - the evidence (the printf from run_experiment not showing) indicates that stdout IS line buffered in this environment. perror shouldn't be, but if he were getting an error from one of those, he wouldn't be hitting the segfault.

Comment: @Michael: Your comments are extremely detailed and very good. I tried adding fflush(stdout) after each `printf()`, but still nothing was shown and the segfault occurs.  I tried removing the `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0)` call, but the segfault still occurred.  As you suggest, I have now updated the program code in the second test, but the segfault still occurs at the beginning of the program.  I've also tried doing 'cat > /dev/ttyS0', and this does work well.  However, as noted above, if I remove the `\r` escape sequence from the string, the program runs!

Comment: @Zack: Thank you very much for suggesting this.